# Android: Cannot cast from View to Chronometer

Tags: android, casting, android-widget, chronometer

I try to follow this example ChronometerDemo.java, but I got some problem:

1. I can't import android.widget.Chronometer; 
   Error: conflicts with a type defined in a same file(import android.widget.Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener)
2. I can't cast View to Chronometer 
   mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

Anyone can help? Appreciate,
Daisy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be another `Chronometer` class present that does not extend from `View`, which is why you can't cast it. It's hard to tell without your code, but did you rename `ChronometerDemo.java` to `Chronometer.java`? `ChronometerDemo` is an Activity, and is not supposed to be returned by a `findViewById` call.

This is, of course, assuming you're talking about [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ChronometerDemo.html).

Comment: Thank you ao much, I got it :))